# Select object using markup in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

Draw a polygon on the dwg file and select the objects lying inside the polygon.

Following is the link of [2d markup](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948) in which i want to select objects within the markup or intersecting the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a custom selection (e.g. via crossing window) you need a code similar to this blog posts: [part iii](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-iii) & [part ii](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-ii), based on `ray tracing` feature.

[image]